# How to create a GitHub Page for an R package sourced from GitHub

Tags: r, github

I'm working on and nearly finished with an R package. I was thinking of taking advantage of GitHub Pages to create a website where I can include images, further detailed instructions, examples, etc. I have another R package on GitHub where the repo is simply the package itself, it can be run easily via `install_github`. Would there be any issue with sourcing a package and hosting GitHub Page in the same repo? Is this outside the intended use of GitHub Pages? I've only recently discovered them and I wanted to explore the option. I saw that it creates a separate branch `gh-pages` but that's as far as I've gone with testing. Keeping branches up-to-date after the first few commits seemed troublesome as my Git experience is also pretty minimal.

Comment: You may want to look into [drat](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/drat.html) for the hosting-a-repo part.  And yes, gh-pages is used quite a bit too.

Comment: RBokeh seems to have the .io page and the package under different accounts and it's not problematic. I think Ramnath's (rCharts, rMaps, etc.) are in the same repo, but GitHub is having issues and won't let me check. They're probably good reference points, though.

Comment: Good luck doing anything with GitHub right now...

Comment: Have you considered writing one or more vignettes instead?  These are a great way to share images, instructions, examples and are a part of your package.

Comment: Never seen one with images, I assume because a lot of people are running R on headless servers.